# How can I document existing API services with RAML?

Tags: raml

We have a project that is pretty nearly done now and has hundreds of existing WEB API Services.
We have documented everything as far as design and example URLs on a wiki as we went.

Now that we are near the end, I have been tasked with finding a product that that is more truly meant to document WEB API services like API Blueprint or Swagger.
I migrated a few API services from our wiki to API Blueprint and Apiary.

But that editor is kind of clunky and now I have stumbled onto RAML and like the human readable syntax much more as well as it's reusability features.

Our second goal however is to be able to use that same API documentation to perform integration testing.

Does anyone know of any tools that could auto document our services without me having to manually move everything over?  I need a kind of an environment that would also support Integration testing.

Comment: In what language/s are the web api services implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language.

For ASP.NET 5 / WebApi you have the [RAML .NET Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cadcb820-762c-4514-9817-884b7558aaa9)

You can check all the available tools [here](http://raml.org/projects/projects) and filter by language and type.

Comment: Yes - thank you.
I have been looking into RAML .NET Tools.

And luckily I was looking at Mulesoft AnyPoint plat form first and got familiar with that first, especially the API Code Editor.

Luckily because RAML .Net Tools plugin ties into that so it's nice to be familiar with it.